# SPARQL, get the next value in a result set based on a total order function

Tags: sparql, rdf

Consider a SPARQL query `q1` with a single head variable `?y`, i.e. `q1(?y) :- some pattern` that has a result set `res(q1)`.

**Problem:**

Given a concrete value `vi` in `res(q1)`, I want to determine the next value `vi+1` in `res(q1)` depending on a specific total order function (for example `<` for integer values).

**Example:**

Consider posing the following query against [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?y where {

 ?x <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?y

}
order by ?y
LIMIT 10
```

This will result in

[image: these results]

Now given the value `vi = 10`, then `vi+1 = 12`, as can be seen from the results.

The only way in my mind to do this is using external programming snippet; that gets a list of ordered SPARQL query results (using`ORDER BY`), goes to `vi`, then retrieves the next value which should be `vi+1`.

**QUESTION:**

Is there any workaround that could express this in SPARQL without the need for coding, (no problem if `vi` is a fixed value in the query)?

Comment: What if resultset is `9, 10, 10, 11`?

Comment: Actually this, in my situation, will not be the case. I select distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's okay to assume that you know `vi` a priori, you could use a filter and a limit to only retrieve `vi+1`

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?y where {

 ?x <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?y
 filter(?y > 10)

}
order by ?y
LIMIT 1
```

The query above yields a single value, `12`

Comment: That was too easy, didn't come across my mind. Thanks!